# What is the proper syntax to get a db instance?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I use eloquent outside laravel.

Here is the file responsible of it:

```
class DbSql
{

    public function db()
    {
        $capsule = new Capsule;
        $capsule->addConnection( [
            'driver'    => Settings::DATABASE_DRIVER,
            'host'      => Settings::DATABASE_HOST,
            'database'  => Settings::DATABASE_NAME,
            'username'  => Settings::DATABASE_USERNAME,
            'password'  => Settings::DATABASE_PASSWORD,
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => ''
        ] );

        # Make this Capsule instance available globally
        $capsule->setAsGlobal();


        return $capsule;
    }

}
```

In controllers, I instantiate the instance once, and may use it several time in a controller:

```
    $dbInstance = ( new DbSql() )->db(); // Create the instance

    // Instance usages:
    $images = $dbInstance->table( 'images_attachments' )->where...
    $files = $dbInstance->table( 'files' )->where...
    .....
```

Should I instantiate with:

`$dbInstance = ( new DbSql() )->db();` as in the code above

or with:

`$dbInstance = ( new DbSql() )->db()->getConnection();`

what's the proper way ?

Comment: If your goal is to use `Eloquent` exactly like it's being used with Laravel, then all you have to do is create `Capsule` object as you have, but instead `$capsule->setAsGlobal()`, you'd use `$capsule->bootEloquent();`. Then simply create and invoke `Capsule` object once and use `Eloquent` as if you were using Laravel (`Class X extends Model { .... }`). If this isn't your intended use, I apologize for wasting your time :)

Comment: have you had a chance to try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to wrap the `Capsule` (which is a `Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager` instance) in another class to make easier to retrieve it. In fact, the `Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager` provides a singleton instance and simple accessors.

Once you call

```
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
```

the `Capsule` instance will be accessible statically from everywhere via `Capsule::`. 
This because the `setAsGlobal()` method, under the hood, does simply this:

```
static::$instance = $this;
```

Saving the instance in a static class variable to retrieve it on subsequent calls to `Capsule::`.
So, once you call `setAsGlobal()`, it is possible to do, for example:

```
Capsule::select('select * from user');
```

and you'll get the results of the query on the previously created connection.

However, you can see that the `select` method doesn't exists on the `Manager` (alias `Capsule`) class. 
Why does it works?
Because the `Manager` class overrides the `__callStatic()` [php magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic)

```
class Manager
{
    use CapsuleManagerTrait;

    // ...

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
    {
        return static::connection()->$method(...$parameters);
    }
}
```

So the call to `select()` method is redirected to the underlying `\Illuminate\Database\Connection` instance **automagically**.

This means that:

- there is no need to wrap the `Manager`/`Capsule` in an external class,  since it is already a wrapper over the `Connection` class. No need to add another wrapper.
- If you prefer to wrap it, however, I suggest you to returning the `Manager`/`Capsule` instance and not the underlying connection, since the suggested approach in the docs is to work directly with the `Manager`